# 'RequestV1' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java

I have the following Java code:

```
RequestV1 request;
...
validateRequest(request);
....
public void validateRequest(final XmlObject request){...}
```

I created this Java Object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class RequestV1 {

    public static class Factory {
        public static RequestV1 newInstance() {
            return new RequestV1();
        }
    }
    ......
}
```

I get error at this line`validateRequest(request);`:

```
Required type: XmlObject
Provided: RequestV1
```

I tried to implement abstract class like this:

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;

@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class RequestV1 implements XmlObject {

    public static class Factory {
        public static RequestV1 newInstance() {
            return new RequestV1();
        }
    }
```

But at this line `return new RequestV1();` I get error: `'RequestV1' is abstract; cannot be instantiated`

I need this new instance to use it like this: `RequestV1 requestV1 = RequestV1.Factory.newInstance();`

Do you know how I can edit `RequestV1` or restructure it so that I can fit all requirements?

I tried to implement abstract class like this:

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;

@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class RequestV1 implements XmlObject {

    public static class Factory {
        public static RequestV1 newInstance() {
            return new RequestV1();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you make `RequestV1` `abstract` then?

Comment: Because without making it abstract I have to implement around 25+ interfaces from `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject`

Comment: Seems like you're mixing up the usecase of the interface `XmlObject` which you might not need to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You **have to implement** the methods of the interface **your class is implementing**. The only shortcut is if there is an actual implementation of the interface meant for users to extend.

Comment: yes, I know. I have to implement around 25+ interfaces from org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject. Any alternatives?

Comment: Why are you trying to implement it?